# Check google play subscription with firebase function

Tags: firebase, google-play-services

I am using firebase functions and I am trying to find out if my users are subscribed to my app by using a firebase function. I wonder how the authentication should be done since I am trying to interface between two google services.

Answer (score 2):

You asked this question a long time ago but since you haven't received an answer yet and for anyone else stumbling across this question:

I found [this blog post](https://medium.com/@msasikanth/google-play-iap-verification-using-cloud-functions-bd8c3a22f9b9) giving a detailed description of how to do so.
It is basically straight forward, but the blog post guides you through it very well, I'm currently following it myself.

*Disclaimer: I haven't published my app yet so I cannot verify if it works. If it doesn't, I will add an edit to this answer.*

Comment: Hi Emil, I know this was a long time ago. But did you managed to verify your subscriptions using the cloud functions?

Comment: @Halen I actually didn't get that far as in the process of setting it all up, we decided to move away from Firebase as our backend and implement our own backend, so I won't be able to confirm anything, sorry

Comment: don't worry, thanks for answering after this long. Cheers!